# How to get the advanced permission of folders and files in powershell?

Tags: powershell, acl

I am trying to get the advanced permission of the folders but can't seem to find a way.

```
$acl = (Get-ACL -Path $path).Access | Where-Object -Property IdentityReference -match $user
```

Currently on this which only provides the basic permission.

Tried this `[System.Enum]::GetNames([System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]` but it only list all the available advanced permission instead of the permissions assigned.

[image: Advanced permission of folder]

Comment: `$acl.FileSystemRights` ?

Comment: @Avshalom I've tried it but it only shows the basic one. Output was just `full control and syncrhonize`